# How to include a graph chart in Magento 2 admin custom module

Tags: magento2, admin

How to create a graph in my custom module in Magento 2 admin side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add graph code into your module:

template code :

```
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

requirejs-config.js

```
  var config = {
   map: {
    '*': {
        highchart:           '<module_name>/js/highcharts.js',
        exporting:           '<module_name>/js/exporting.js',
        customjs:           '<module_name>/js/custom.js',
       }
   }
}
```

Your custom js:

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
       }]
   });
});
```

(NOTE: You need to edit custom js data to set your module data)

For more information you can refer [This](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)  and you can find other type of charts too.

Comment: Thanks alot..Instead of requirejs-config.js, I include in xml (<link src="<module_name>/js/jquery.min.js"/>
        <link src="<module_name>/js/highcharts.js"/>
        <link src="<module_name>/js/custom.js"/>). this works fine for me...

Comment: Any Time Happy to help :)

Comment: am follow the same steps but nothing is shown

Comment: Third party js is not include in this way . 

You should use `shim` for adding third party JS